# System/ X freezes graphically on function keys press

Tags: x11, keyboard, freeze, intel-graphics

Not entirely sure why, but shortly after running a system upgrade, ie. `sudo pacman -Syyu`, it appears that my entire graphical environment freezes on the keypress of any of half my function keys, such as <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, and the media keys which for me are <kbd>F6</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>.

I've tried rebinding and unbinding these keys assuming it might be tied to something they are set to execute (I use them frequently), as it so turns out, this is not the case. Regardless of my modifications or input, any time I press one of my function keys, my entire graphical environment gets shot, I have to open `TTY2` and `pkill x`, and run `startx` again bringing back up all of my previous applications etc.

This is becoming extremely irritating, as it so turns out, I accidentally hit another function key while typing this sentence and had to restart... This will heavily impede workflow and focus if I'm constantly restarting parts of my core system because it can't handle me hitting a key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I also run Arch linux and had the same thing happen to me after my last system update. To narrow down the cause, I commented out all the lines in my `.xinitrc` and then uncommented them one by one, each time restarting X and seeing if pressing function keys caused a freeze. You could try doing this; I know it's pretty generic advice, but it worked for me in this case.

For me the cause has something to do `dbus`, although I haven't figured out why. But disabling `dbus` definitely fixes the freezing.

Comment: In my case, I was using i3, so I changed my .xinitrc to run `exec i3` instead of using dbus-launch